# Rolling back transaction with Oracle OCCI

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, occi

I have code similar to the simple example below that is trying to rollback a database write when an error occurs. However, half of the data seems to be left in the database rather than being deleted/rolled back.

```
statement->setAutoCommit(false);
statement->setMaxIterations(3);

int counter = 1;
try
{
    statement->setInt(1, 1);
    statement->addIteration();

    statement->setInt(1, 2);
    statement->addIteration();

    statement->setInt(1, 3);
    statement->executeUpdate();

    statement->setInt(1, 4);
    statement->addIteration();

    statement->setInt(1, 2); // ERROR HERE (Unique constraint)
    statement->addIteration();

    statement->setInt(1, 6);
    statement->executeUpdate();

    connection->commit();
}
catch (oracle::occi::SQLException ex)
{
    connection->rollback();
    connection->terminateStatement(statement);
    throw DatabaseException(ex.what());
}
```

If I get an Oracle error thrown then I want to roll back the current transaction so that NO rows were written. However this doesn't seem to be working properly.

I have a write that fails half way through, and it doesn't successfully roll back the rows. I end up with half of the data written out to the database.

Am I missing something with the `setAutoCommit(false)` and `connection->rollback()` command?

Comment: I have never used Oracle, but don't you need to `commit` the statements after the last statement? As far as I know, the changes get permanent on DB only after executing the `commit` statement.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right. I'll add it in to my example. Unfortunately that's not the problem I'm trying to fix, the problem here is that it IS committing rather than rolling back.

Comment: Oh, I am not able to help you there. But, Did you try creating save point and rolling back to that save point? Are you sure, the rollback command is called at the line where unique constraint fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a side-effect of [batch error processing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci04sql.htm#i441668) you should try and call setBatchErrorMode( false ) if you want an exception to be raised on error. Otherwise you can also use the batch-error mode and check the collected errors and decide if you want to commit or rollback

Comment: Interesting, I'll give batch errors a shot. I believe that batchErrorMode is false by default, but I will try it out on Monday

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley How did it go ?

Comment: Thanks @Falco it is working now, I set batchErrorMode to true and explicitly handled the statement level errors.